# Some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database.Idea 13.1.2

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

i am using intellij Idea 13.1.2 i want to use svn project on Idea, but
`Some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database.`

How can i pass this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem... Downloaded http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/ and show svn.exe path to Intellij Idea.